# Document library document template versioning

Tags: document-library, document-template

I want to enable versioning with SharePoint 2013 document library document template but could not find an option. I searched on google but no luck. Does anyone know there is any option or a way to achieve this? We want to keep track on each and every change made on template so we can restore previous version if needed.

Comment: Are you aware of it for SP2010?

Comment: No. Currently we use SP 2013. Is there any option with SP2010 and not in 2013?

Comment: We encounter this issue recently. The answer is no, you can't set versioning for document template. When you update the document template the old template will automatically send to recycle bin. where it will be deleted in 30 days or as per your retention policy. If you want to restore it back, you need to rename existing template using SharePoint designer. Then restore deleted file from recycle bin.